# Configure azure Enterprise app include extra data in id_token claims (OpenID connect)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have my OpenID Connect access via Azure AD setup and it works just fine.

Using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me'?$select=onPremisesExtensionAttributes` we can access the extentionAttributes from our AD given the `access_token` for the user in question.

However, I'd like to know whether it is possible to change the `Azure app Manifest` configuration such that the data returned by the GRAPH api call above is included in the `id_token` claims (thus only needed one call to Azure instead of the OpenID Connect call + a GRAPH api call).

So far none of the `Microsoft | Learn` pages I've read, have mentioned that this *should not be possible*.

So far I haven't been able to add any `optionalClaims` that have produced the data from the Graph API, nor have I found an explicit statement that one cannot do this.

Any ideas? Either to what is needed to have in the `Manifest` to be able to access the data from `$select=onPremisesExtensionAttributes` or an explicit statement that one cannot do this and one'd need to do a seperate call to the Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

> **Note** that: Through Azure app Manifest, the data from Microsoft Graph API call (i.e., extension properties) cannot be included in the id token optional claims. Refer  [**this**](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims).

*As a workaround*, you need to do a separate Graph call to get the `onPremisesExtensionAttributes` like below:

I created an **Azure AD Application** and granted API permissions:

[image]

I generated **access token** by using the below parameters:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientId
grant_type:authorization_code
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
code:code
redirect_uri:https://jwt.ms
client_secret:ClientSecret
```

[image]

By using the above generated access token, I am able to get the **`onPremisesExtensionAttributes`** successfully as below:

```json
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=onPremisesExtensionAttributes
```

[image]

> I'd like to know whether it is possible to change the `Azure appManifest` configuration such that the data returned by the GRAPH api call above is included in the `id_token` claims (thus only needed one call to Azure instead of the OpenID Connect call + a GRAPH api call).

Yes, you can call only one API to Azure. If you try calling both OpenID Connect call + a GRAPH Api call, then it will consider the first scope like below:

I used the scope as `api://AppID/test.write user.read`

[image]

When I decoded the token the Graph API is not included in the token like below:

[image]

**Hence**, you need to do two calls one for OpenID and another for Graph API.

Comment: That first quote? Where did that come from? It is not the openid spec page.

Comment: AFAIK your requirement is to add data from the Microsoft Graph API call to be included in the id token optional claims which is currently not possible.

Comment: All I know is that I can access it via a GRAPH API call. I just do not knot if there are other ways to access the same piece of information. I have seen several examples of adding extension data to the manifest. (they are all called `extension_<ID without-s>_xxx`), I just don't know if there is an interface the the `id_token` setup can use to access the same data,

Comment: Right now I cannot re-find the MS Learn page that listed that some graph data could be included in the `id_token` claim.

Comment: AFAIK, we cannot do it. Could you try to find the document and paste it here.

Comment: This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/extensibility-overview?tabs=http#choose-an-extension-type-for-your-application at least lists the possibility to access the extentionattribute data via connect. Though I might be misreading it

Comment: The documentation gives the info on getting the open extensions via Graph API. But no information on including it in ID token.

Comment: Exactly. I think it was this one https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/userinfo#consider-using-an-id-token-instead I was looking at. It mentions the possibility to add stuff as optional claims for the `id_token`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252345/discussion-between-rukmini-and-daleif).